# SQL Server HierarchyID: How to add children w/o knowing the ID of the child?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

From a table variable `@Toc` I need to insert content into the table `PE_TableOfContents`, which has a HIERARCHYID.  In `PE_TableOfContents` there will be a root item.  From that root item, I can get the root HIERARCHYID (`@rootNode`).

But then when I go to insert children, I am unsure of how to create the new HIERARCHYID, as I won't know the ID of that column until after it's inserted.

```
DECLARE @rootNode HIERARCHYID = (SELECT tocNode from PE_TableOfContents WHERE TocNodeLevel = 0)

INSERT INTO PE_TableOfContents (
    TocNode,
    ... all of the other columns)
SELECT 
    @rootNode.ToString + ???? + '/',
    T... all of the other columns
FROM 
    @Toc T
```

I'm looking over all the docs for [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-2017), and maybe I'm missing something, but I'm not seeing this.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that's not immediately obvious from the documentation on HierarchyID is that you're free to specify whatever numeric data you want as the constituents of the path. I personally like to use the auto-generated ID (whether an identity value or otherwise). I also like to put something like `ParentID` as a column in the table so that if something goes sideways in keeping the hierarchyid column up to date, you can use a recursive query to re-generate it (which is to say that the hierarchyid column is derived data that is there only to aid in query performance).

To be explicit, let's say I had the following table:

```
ID      ParentID
================
100       NULL
200       100
300       100
400       200
```

I'd derive the hierarchyid column like this:

```
ID      ParentID   h
=========================
100       NULL     /100/
200       100      /100/200
300       100      /100/300
400       200      /100/200/400
```

I can't think of a way to do this w/o first inserting the row with a `null` value for the hierarchyid if you're using an identity column. If you're using a Sequence to allocate the ID you can get a value from the sequence and use it both for the ID value and to derive the hierarchyid.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after enough google searches, I [found a good explanation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/D0AsD8j1kT4).

First, get the root (or parent) node:

```
DECLARE @rootNode HIERARCHYID = (SELECT tocNode FROM PE_TableOfContents WHERE TocNodeLevel = 0)
```

Then, get the last known child of that root (or parent) node:

```
DECLARE @lastNode HIERARCHYID = (SELECT MAX(tocNode) FROM PE_TableOfContents WHERE tocNode.GetAncestor(1) = @rootNode);
```

Then do the insert as follows:

```
INSERT INTO PE_TableOfContents (
    TocNode,
    ... all of the other columns)
SELECT         
    @rootNode.GetDescendant(@lastNode, NULL),
    T... all of the other columns
FROM 
    @Toc T
```